# Google Plus sticky TabHost

Tags: android, scrollview, google-plus, android-tabhost

I want to emulate Google Plus Android app's profile page, where you have a `TabHost` that seems to be inside an `ScrollView` but when you scroll, it not only pins to the top of the bar, but each tab itself starts acting like a `ListView`.

I need some ideas to think out of the box, cause this seems like a nested `ScrollView` kind of thing

Comment: what is sticky in  this tabhost ?

Comment: as you scroll, the tabhost gets pinned to the top of the screen

Comment: plz give me screenshot

Comment: sad, that there is still no answer